# Extractin LP model from AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I have a very big and complicated LP model in **AMPL**. I need to extract `Ax<= b` format from my **LP** (i.e), I need to extract all my data in form of matrix `A`, `b`, and all variables to be concatenate into a large vector `x`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are familiar with coding for example in Java you could use an open source library/solver called GLPK.

In there you can read your .mod file and extract your data from the A and b Matrix. I am sure that the commercial software such as CPLEX/ Gurobi can also do that (also academic license available). Here you can find the user guide for GLPK: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/glpk-doc/glpk.pdf

Look for the following:

- glp get mat row — retrieve row of the constraint matrix

perhaps this could help.